# Error Making prediction with python onnxruntime

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, onnx, onnxruntime

I have created an very basic decision tree using the `sklearn` library. This tree is trained based on 4 features:

```
feat1 INT
feat2 INT
feat3 FLOAT
feat4 FLOAT
```

And the label/target feature is a boolean value (0 or 1).

I converted the tree into a `ONNX` format and now I want to use the `onnxruntime python` library to make a prediction. I have found example code on the internet to do this. The problem is I dont understand exactly what exacly happens in all parts of this code, functions and parameters. This leads to me getting an error. I did search for some documentation, but I cant find this.

In below code I convert the tree model to `ONNX` format. This is succesfull but parts of the code I dont understand. In the `initial_type` variable, what do I have to enter here based on the 4 feature columns and label/target feature I mensioned earlier? Now I have entered `FloatTensorType([None, 4]` because I have 4 feature columns and what the `None` does I have no idea.

```
##Convert to ONNX format

initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, 4]))]
onx = convert_sklearn(treeModel, initial_types=initial_type)
with open("path", "wb") as f:
    f.write(onx.SerializeToString())
```

In below code I want to make a prediction using the `onnxruntime` library but I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Either type_proto was null or it was not of sequence type
```

This is because I dont understand the last line of code below. I entered this `{input_name: [4, 8, 77.8, 143.45]` because this are four values for the feature columns. What am I doing wrong here?

```
sess = rt.InferenceSession("pathToONNXModel")
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
label_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name
pred_onx = sess.run([label_name], {input_name: [4, 8, 77.8, 143.45]})[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `{input_name: numpy.array([4, 8, 77.8, 143.45], dtype=numpy.float32)}`? onnxruntime requires numpy arrays as inputs.